# Looping over registered variable from multiple items per inventory host

Tags: ansible

I have the following sample inventory (trimmed for brevity):

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    foo1.example.com:
      disks:
        - disk: /dev/sdaa
        - disk: /dev/sdab
        - disk: /dev/sdac
        - disk: /dev/sdad
    foo2.example.com:
      disks:
        - disk: /dev/sdaa
        - disk: /dev/sdab
        - disk: /dev/sdac
        - disk: /dev/sdad
```

I have a play where I loop over each disk and perform a shell command on each one and register the output. Basically stdout will be 'true' or 'false'.

```yaml
- name: "Checking disk health"
  shell: /sbin/smartctl -H -j {{ item.disk }} | jq '.smart_status.passed'
  register: passed
  with_items:
    - "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].disks }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "/sbin/smartctl -H -j {{ item.disk }}"
```

For some reason I can't figure out how to loop over this in an assert statement. I know I've done something like this before years ago but can't find my notes or any examples.

For each host, I need to loop over each disk's output and assert that passed == true.

When I execute the following debug play:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - passed
```

I get this output (trimmed for brevity):

```
ok: [foo1.example.com] => (item=passed) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "passed",
    "passed": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/sbin/smartctl -H -j /dev/sdaa | jq '.smart_status.passed'",

                "stdout": "true",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "true"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/sbin/smartctl -H -j /dev/sdab | jq '.smart_status.passed'",

                "stdout": "true",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "true"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/sbin/smartctl -H -j /dev/sdac | jq '.smart_status.passed'",

                "stdout": "true",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "true"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "/sbin/smartctl -H -j /dev/sdad | jq '.smart_status.passed'",

                "stdout": "true",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "true"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side preliminary notes:

- `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].disks }}` can be shortened to `{{ disks }}`
- `{{ disks }}` is a list so you should not pass it as a list of list to you loop (even though `with_items` is flattening transparently for you...)

Now in the following task (fixed as per my above remarks):

```yaml
- name: "Checking disk health"
  shell: /sbin/smartctl -H -j {{ item.disk }} | jq '.smart_status.passed'
  register: passed
  with_items: "{{ disks }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "/sbin/smartctl -H -j {{ item.disk }}"
```

you are registering a result from a looped task in the variable `passed`

As explained in the [documentation on loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) and in the [documentation on variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables), registers from loop are modified to include a top `results` element which is a list of all individual results in the loop.

If I understand well you want to test in these `results` all element have `"true"` in their `stdout` attribute. You don't need to loop for that you can check that in a single run.

What I would do is demonstrated in the example below: extract all `stdout` attributes from the `results` list, map each element with the `bool` filter to convert to a real boolean value, and use the `all` test to make sure all values are `True`.

```yaml
- name: Assert all disks passed the smartctl test
  assert:
    that: (passed.results | map(attribute='stdout') | map('bool') | list) is all
    msg: One or more disks failed the test
```